# Design Database schema, Mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a table for Users and one for Cards (at least 900 rows). Each user can have multiple cards (list of cards), also each user can have some preferential cards (10 / 8 the number must be flexible). Now I try to create a schema that can be flexible in future. My (not really good) idea is to have a table with (user_id / card_id / card_type (list/preferential) ), but in the end I will have to many rows. I'm using Laravel & Mysql.
 Any better solutions?

Comment: your solution is good. Cards table will be like a library)

Comment: If I have at least 100 users with 910 cards, I will have to do interrogation in over 9.100, and this is a good scenarios, If I will increase user/cards, will be more, that why I'm not sure, about performance.

Comment: it's a Many-To-Many relationship, this is normal things) don't afraid this numbers :D

Comment: I wouldn't be concerned with your table sizes. You won't notice any performance degradation until you're working with hundreds of thousands or more rows.

Comment: Cool, so that I will do, thank you!